# Rake secret command not working

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rake, secret-key

When I run `rake secret` in my terminal, instead of getting a new key, i get

```
NoMethodError: undefined method 'reject' for #<String: blah blah blah>
c:/Sites/appname/config/application.rb:10:in '<module:appname>'
c:/Sites/appname/config/application.rb:9:in '<top (required)>'
c:/Sites/appname/Rakefile:4:in '<top (required)>'
```

I've checked that those three lines are identical to the ones of a known good project.

I'm using ruby 2.0.0
rails 4.1.1
I'm in my current project folder.

When i run rake secret in my other projects, the command works, but not when I run it from this new project.

Comment: what is the project Rails -v?

Comment: Please see the error message carefully, it says there is error for the string. > NoMethodError: undefined method 'reject' for #<String: blah blah blah> Please resolve this error and try again.

Comment: I don't know what that means or how to do that. I didn't type `rake reject`, i typed `rake secrets`

Comment: @gwho, check your file application.rb:10

Comment: It says `  class Application < Rails::Application` just like my other project.

Comment: @brunozrk I'm not sure what you mean. what command should I run? When I run rails -v, it's `Rails 4.1.1`

Comment: Do you have file `bin/rake` i your app?

Comment: yes, the contents are `#!/usr/bin/env ruby.exe
require_relative '../config/boot'
require 'rake'
Rake.application.run
`

Comment: No,no. I say in your project. <you_project_name>/bin/rake

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/60997/discussion-between-gwho-and-brunozrk).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue was with the figaro gem. it broke all rails s commands, and rake commands. I haven't figured out how to fix it yet, but more to come soon.

Edit:

The error was typo in the application.yml file used by figaro.

Answer (score 0):

The typo the original poster mentions is using = for key/value pairs in application.yml

So instead of using username = 'someusername' use
                    username: 'someusername'

hope this helps somebody